# Problems with ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04

my ubuntu was suddenly like this:

[image]

I can't even open the nine points on the bottom right

what could it be, how to solve?

Answer (score 0):

it is very hard to find out the root cause of the problem because of the lack of evidences!! . but my advices to you are this:

1. reboot you system
2. did you completely installed the OS(without any error)?
3. make sure that your that you can access the terminal by ctrl+alt+t and check for the logs in dmesg command
4. make sure that you system has enough hardware configuration for the ubuntu to successfully boots (RAM,CPU,Eough space in hard drive,...)

Answer (score 0):

Try pushing Ctrl+Alt+F1 and running `sudo apt update`

Comment: Please [edit] your answer to **explain** what this does and how it helps!

Comment: Ctrl+Alt+F1 will put them on the graphical GDM login screen. Not useful. Maybe they meant Ctrl+Alt+F3.

Comment: @guntbert. Sorry for my delay.  The problem suddenly disappeared after i reboot and run apt-get update; apt-get upgrade. Still trying to understand what actually happened.